# Google Sheets - How can I find the first row number containing specific text, and then clear/delete all content to end?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently importing a bunch of data and then splitting it into multiple columns and then attempting to clear or delete any erroneous rows (it's a raw data import that contains a bunch of scrap rows).

So far I've got the data imported, split, & sorted.  Now I'm trying to find the row number, based on a value in column A, and then select all rows to the end of the sheet to either delete or clear the content.

I'm to the point where all of my data has been split into the columns I need (A:J) and sorted so that all relevant data is at the top (it's a variable data set) so now I'm just trying to find the first row that contains "----------------------" as this will be my first 'garbage' row.

```
outputrange.setValues(output);
pull1.deleteRows(1, 40);
pull1.getRange(2, 1, pull1.getLastRow()-1, 
pull1.getLastColumn()).activate().sort({column:2, ascending: true});

    var removalValues = range.getValues()
    for (var j=0; j<removalValues.length; j++) {
      var rowArray = removalValues[j];
      for (var k=0; k<rowArray.length; k++) {
        var columnValue = rowArray[k];
        if (rowArray[0] === "----------------------") {

          var rowNumber = i;
          pull1.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, pull1.getLastColumn()).activate()
        }
      }
    }
```

I've attempted the code above to loop through and find the correct cell reference, and just temporarily highlight the row so I make sure it's functioning correctly.  Currently this part of my code processes but otherwise doesn't do anything.  Really I just need something that will look through my data in column A and find the matching data, then return the row number for me so that I can apply it to other formulas.

Edit: I updated my code using some additional resources and came up with the following.  It *seems* to work correctly but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient solution:

```
        var outputrange = pull1.getRange(startRow, 1, LR-startRow+1, 10)
        outputrange.setValues(output);
        pull1.deleteRows(1, 40);
        pull1.getRange(2, 1, pull1.getLastRow()-1, 
        pull1.getLastColumn()).activate().sort({column:2, ascending: true});

        var rangeData = pull1.getDataRange();
        var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
        var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
        var searchRange = pull1.getRange(1,1,lastRow-1,lastColumn-1);
        var removalValues = searchRange.getValues();

        for (j=0; j < lastColumn-1; j++) {
          for (k=0; k < lastRow-1; k++) {
            if(removalValues[k][j] === "----------------------") {
              pull1.getRange(k+1, 1, pull1.getLastRow(), 10).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);

            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Find specified text then delete all rows below said text.

---

#### Solution:

Use `textFinder` to find the text then pass the result row to `deleteRows()`.

```
function findAndClear() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
  var range = sh.getRange(1, 1, lastRow);

  //find specified text and return row number
  var row = range.createTextFinder('----------------------').findNext().getRow();

  //calculate number of rows to delete
  var delRows = lastRow - row;

  //delete rows
  sh.deleteRows(row, delRows);
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

First of all, sorry but I've scrapped the script you were using. There's no need to get all of the values in the column then loop through each one, it's over-complicated and slow.

Using `textFinder` is much quicker, no looping through arrays, just finding the first occurrence of your string in column A and getting the row number.

---

#### Notes:

If you did want to keep the row containing your string, use:

```
sh.deleteRows(row + 1, delRows);
```

---

#### References:

1. [`textFinder` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: That's perfect!  Thank you so much!  I figured there was probably a more efficient way than what I was using, that just ended up being something I cobbled together that worked at the time.